# Center both h1 and h2 horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

How do I align an `h1` and `h2` both vertically and horizontally, while keeping the height 100% of the viewport?

I've added `align-items: center; justify-content: center;` to the container and `text-align: center; vertical-align: center;` to the header class. Adding `display: block;` to either does nothing.

#### Expected:

[image: How I want it to look]

#### Actual:

[image: How mine looks]

What's going one exactly? Is it the navbar?

```css
#welcome-section {
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.welcome-header {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="welcome-section">
  <h1 class="welcome-header">Namaste, Kevin here.</h1>
  <h2 class="welcome-header">And I'm a front-end developer</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: You could look into this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div

Comment: the `align-items` and `justify-content` properties are for elements with `display: flex;`. Have you tried adding `display: flex;` to your `#welcome-section`? You may also need `flex-direction: column`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use flex alignement properties, then the flex display is required.

```
#welcome-section {
  height: 100vh;
  display:flex;/*this is  what was missing */
  flex-flow:column;/*this is  what was missing too*/
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MqJgVG

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

#welcome-section {
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;       /*this is  what was missing */
  flex-flow: column;  /*this is  what was missing too*/
}

.welcome-header {
  text-align: center;
  /*vertical-align: center; useless*/
}
```

```html
<div id="welcome-section">
  <h1 class="welcome-header">Namaste, Kevin here.</h1>
  <h2 class="welcome-header">And I'm a front-end developer</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you - what's the difference between `flex-flow` and `flex-direction`? `flex-direction: column;` had no impact

Comment: Flex-flow sets the direction and can also sets behavior wrap or reverse. Flex-direction should work

Answer (score 0):

Set your parent class to relative

```
#welcome-section {
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position:relative;
}
```

Then wrap your welcome-header with both your `h1` `h2` tags
And make it absolute and center it:

```
.welcome-header {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:50%;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}


<div id="welcome-section">
  <div class="welcome-header">
    <h1>Namaste, Kevin here.</h1>
    <h2>And I'm a front-end developer</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wEgwYd?editors=1100)